# Forcing an element to :hover with JavaScript when dragging an element over it. No jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop

I've found a couple of search results here but they're all for jQuery and the couple I looked at weren't applicable to my case.

This is a small project and I've avoided using jQuery so far. I want to keep it like that as to not need the library.

Basically, I'm dragging an `<article>` element to a `<div>` element. The div has the `background-image` of a closed trashbin. In the CSS it is set to display the same, but open, trashbin when `:hover` is triggered.

Now, when I pull my article element to the div, the `:hover` effect isn't being triggered.
How do I do this?

All required elements are set `draggable` and the needed event listeners have been added, Console.log confirms they work.

Comment: :hover is meant for when a pointing devices designates but doesn't activate an element. That's not what you're doing here, so a browser won't request the CSS update. ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes )

Comment: You can use `mouseover`/`mouseout` to append a classname to the element.

Comment: putting "No jQuery" in your title is not going to help the 95% of traffic from search engines. Just by not using the jQuery tag, any jQuery answer will mostly be downvoted to death

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a CSS class called 'open_trash' and set the background image of a open trash there and then you can use javascript to change the class of the dragged element on mousedown like this

```
document.getElementById("draggedItem").className = "open_trash";
```

You can set the class name to either an empty string or something else onmousedown.

Comment: didn't work, ended up doing a style.backGroundImage manipulation.